# Find all tables in a database with Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, resultset, h2

I'm trying to get all the table names in my database back through Java but I am having problems using the Result Set.
The below works and I can see the info listed when I inspect the result set. 
How do i get the table names from the result set into a collection?.

```
ResultSet rs;
rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES");
```

Comment: http://www.jdbc-tutorial.com/jdbc-tutorials/jdbc-result-sets

Comment: Iterate over it and add each value of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the *ResultSet* object in a loop:

```
ResultSet rs;
rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES");

List ll = new LinkedList();

// Fetch each row from the result set
while (rs.next()) {
  String tableName = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");

  ll.add(tableName);
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, i was over complicating things as im not that familiar with the API

Answer (score 1):

The same way you get the results from any other `ResultSet` into a collection:

```
List<String> tableNames = new ArrayList<>();
while (rs.next()) {
    tableNames.add(rs.getString(1));
}
```